# Why is B always not 0

Tags: magnetic-fields

I discovered that while applying Ampere's law,
For a solenoid..
B inside is calculated.

But outside we say the loop encloses no net current or hence there should not be any field..

Let's say for example a conducting wire carrying current i

we have,

B=Something

But we can always have a current with opposite direction at infinity and hence an amperian loop of infinite radius

and thus B to be a zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampère's law does not say that the field is zero if there is no enclosed current. It says that if you integrate $B.d\ell$ round a loop then the result will be zero if there is no enclosed current.

For example consider this loop in a constant magnetic field $B$:

[image: Ampere]

Even though the magnetic field is non-zero, for every $d\ell$ in the loop there is a matching $d\ell$ pointing in the other direction and the two values of $B.d\ell$ will cancel out. This means the integral round the lop is zero even though $B$ is non-zero.

As Rijul says, Ampère's law only applies in some circumstances i.e. when the current density is not changing with time. However it does apply in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Ampere law's results are not always accurate as the law relies on approximation to calculate magnetic field of simple symmetric current distributions.

Even in a solenoid field is present outside of solenoid, you can try it at you home by making one, the field strength will be low because of less distance between the two ends of each loop which makes a solenoid. However if you assume current carrying counterpart to your wire at infinite distance, the field at both sides of wire will be significang is hence easily noticeable.

Comment: In a simple/home made solenoid you would wrap wires about a thin tube or something else, the radius of each wire loop would be very less, to make a zero magnetic field outside of solenoid the field of two diametrically opposite ends of wire are supposed to cancel, since the distance will be less, cancelation would be significant and field strength will be low.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. The issue is not a practical one.